# how to use broadcast receiver on receive event

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

i have a project that when run application one service be active and when device be turn on my android service be active.
the project run in device's internal memory successfully but when i install it on external memory and reboot my device again don't work!

for first i call my service in first acitivity and it works, but when i reboot my device it doesn't work !

my activity :

```
   public class FirstClass extends Activity 
   {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
            startActivity(new Intent(FirstClass.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    },5000);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
   }
```

my broadcast receiver :

```
 public class BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
      context.startService(startServiceIntent);
  }
 }
```

i added :

```
    <service
        android:name="com.dariran.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
    <receiver android:name="com.dariran.BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

to appliation tag on Manifest.xml and

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: soheila, so you not getting Boot receiver properly?

Comment: my app works when i insstall it on internal device memory

Comment: So what is the problem you getting? When device will be turned on at that time its not working?

Comment: look, my app work when it is on memory of phone but not work on external memory

Comment: What does that mean? how you make it seperate? Whenever it installs, it must work.

Comment: Then keep it in phone memory, why you installing in External memory.

Comment: mean when the apk file installed on internal memory works but wheen install on external memory doesn't work

Comment: I dont think so it matters, no difference whenever you install, it must not be reflected too much after installing.

Comment: is this MyService is a STICKY service...???

Comment: no it is very simple

Comment: have you launched the ap after moving to sdcard ..?? if not, then do it once..then go for a reboot,  also add these permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> if not there,  and also try by adding : <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" /> inside intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

i added this code to my service class to put a filter to recognize the external storage but don't work again :(

```
    @Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    try {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
        BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you go for a STICKY service, It seems more suitable for your purpose, am sory if I am wrong, I am telling this without understanding all your requirement.